# Создание модального окна с прогресс баром

Tags: c++, qt

По нажатию на кнопку из пункта меню, происходит сначала вызов прогресс бара по истечению 5 секунд переход на диалоговое окно. 
Попытался сделать вот так не получилось

```
    ProgressBar *progressbar = new ProgressBar(0);
    progressbar->setModal(true);
    progressbar->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    progressbar->exec();

    ManualSetting * dialogManualSetting = new 
    ManualSetting(sensormanager,0); 
    dialogManualSetting->setModal(true);
    dialogManualSetting->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialogManualSetting->exec();
```

В ProgressBar реализовал таймер который отсчитывает 5 секунд и закрывает ProgressBar. Но когда запустил то увидал сначала переход в ProgressBar по закрытие снова в меню и только потом  ManualSetting. Попытался добавить ProgressBar в конструктор ManualSetting но проблема не пропала. В общем нужно сначала перейти в progressbar --->

Answer (score 0):

```
progressbar->setWindowFlags(progressbar->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```